# how to make custom avd and xml editor configuration in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have one android device having resolution of 1024x768 and it is 9.7".I want to make custom avd as well xml editor configuration(as per attached image).how can i create the exact one.I have tried but not able to create perfectly.
[image]